# Global models for time series prediction with series of different lengths

Tags: time-series, clustering, data-cleaning

As I haven't found much on the topic, I wanted to start the discussion about local- (iteratively for every column) vs. global models (only one iteration per forecast horizon, ex ante).

As this is a big topic with many different angles, I want to focus on the question of how well global models perform compared to local models on a dataset with time series of different lengths (one may start 2016 the next one 2017 and so on).

For local models this is not an issue, as it is simple in this case to start every ts modeling at the actual start date of the series.
If I want to use global models for the same problem, I will probably struggle getting satisfactory accuracy results.
To overcome this struggle I propose several techniques that I want to test:

1. the most obvious way is to cluster your time series. You need to make clusters of the same length. This is will result with many time series containing some leading NA values, or losing data when cutting the NA containing tails.
2. There might be another approach to clustering like dtw to make homogenous clusters, with less effort. I like this idea, but there is not much documentation on who to exactly do it.
3. Like approach number one, with the difference of replacing leading NA with linear interpolation or kalman filtering.

Please let me know about your ideas and how you think of the global approach for this time series problem in general.

I am using recursive ensembles from modeltime to do the job, as you might want to know.

If there is no sufficient answer to this question and you would rather experiment to find the right solution, I might deliver a reprex. So far I am just curious if there is some solid experience on this topic available.

Comment: For the theory on this problem, see https://robjhyndman.com/publications/global-forecasting/. tldr; Global models are surprisingly good, even with series that are not similar.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the provided information on the topic! If what this implicates is true and my guesses are correct, the global approach might save me days of writing data cleaning procedures. I have to try it out first thing in the morning